# trouble htaccess redirects non-www page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

newbie on htaccess and redirects, I hope someone can help me with this. At the moment all but one http urls are redirecting correctly to https.

The following script has been updated as requested to remove the duplicate, the problem still persists.

Examples followed:

http://example.com redirects to https://www.example.com/

http://www.example.com redirects to https://www.example.com/

http://subdomain.example.com redirects to https://subdomain.example.com

Trouble comes when

http://example.com/somepage this only redirects to https://www.example.com/

Following is a snip from my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` two times? The second cannot be reached anyways.

Comment: I've been trying to fix this, must've left it in there. Do you think I should remove it?

Comment: Yes, you should. Then update your question with your actual code

Comment: anyone? still can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is a valid way of redirecting all non https:// calls to their secure versions. Using this would redirect http://example.com/somepage to https://www.example.com/somepage

Perhaps your 301 is just cached? Clear your cache and try again. I would recommend using [R=302] flags until you confirm the redirects are working and then update your .htaccess to use 301's.